How to ensure that pytest-defined `request` fixture is available?
I'm still wrestling with how/when I can use pytest's off-the-shelf fixtures (e.g.: request). I have a class structure of the form:
abc.ABC -> TestBase -> IntegrationTestBase -> SomeSpecialTest

In IntegrationTestBase, I defined a teardown_method like so:
def teardown_method(self, method, request):
    ...

However, my test, when invoked, fails to inject the fixture:
teardown_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

I have successfully referred to the request fixture in a test method itself, but not in a parent class (IntegrationTestBase, above). Is there any special syntax I need for the parent class teardown_method to get the request fixture?

I did try adding @pytest.mark.usefixtures('request') to IntegrationTestBase, to no avail.

Those methods don't support fixtures, as you're seeing (didn't find this specifically documented, but e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78967342/3001761). What are you actually trying to do with this arrangement?


Those methods don't support fixtures, as you're seeing

Yeah, I was worried that was the case :(

What are you actually trying to do with this arrangement? –

I want to capture the test method status (passed, failed, e.g.) and emit it as part of some extra output I'm generating.

I got it working by doing the following:

Added a hook (in conftest.py) to capture call information:

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)



Implemented a fixture to wrap setup/teardown logic; note the use of request.node.rep_call.outcome to access the wrapped function's return value in the teardown logic:

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def fixture_method(self, request):
    do_some_start_stuff()
    yield
    do_some_teardown_stuff(request.node.rep_call.outcome)

